# Why is my arraylist not getting sorted using comparator interface?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

So i tried sorting an arraylist which consists of only integer elements in descending order using comparator interface but after printing the array list it shows the elements in the order in which input was given.

here's my code...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static class Sort implements Comparator<Integer>{
        public int compare(Integer a,Integer b){
            if(a<b){
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        ArrayList<Integer> arraylist=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            arraylist.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
        }
        Collections.sort(arraylist,new Sort());
        System.out.println(arraylist);
        br.close();
    }
}
```

So what i learnt is that if the compare method returns a positive value then swapping of the objects take place. So i returned `1` if `a<b` for sorting the array in descending order. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: How about `a>b`? In your code `0` is returned in that case (which translates to equality).

Comment: Just `return b - a;`

Comment: @Bohemian: That can fail due to overflow.

Comment: well in case of a>b or a=b i don't need to swap the numbers so returning anything other than +ve value is fine i think

Comment: @manofculture: No, it's really *not* fine. Your `Sort` class violates the contract of `Comparator`. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T): "The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`." That's not satisfied by your class.

Comment: @manofculture why don't you need to swap the numbers in case `a>b`? Let me put it this way: How about `b<a`?

Comment: @Jon Skeet
thanks a ton now i understood

Comment: As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-), the `compare()` implementation must be transitive, but yours is not.

Comment: @gthanop even better, let's not think about "swapping", since that's just an implementation detail of the sorting method used. The concept that "if the compare method returns a positive value then swapping of the objects take place" (according to OP) is just wrong to begin with.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca yep my understanding of the concept was wrong. thanks for your time

Comment: `Integer.compare(b, a)`  could (should) be used instead of `b - a` (to avoid eventual integer overflow)

Answer (score 7):

As the Comments discuss, your code violates the terms of the `Comparator` contract. [Per Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617973/why-is-my-arraylist-not-getting-sorted-using-comparator-interface/70618033#comment124835260_70617973), the Javadoc explains that "The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y."

And, you are working too hard.

When you want to reverse the order, descending rather than ascending, simply call [`Comparator#reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed()). This call returns a new `Comparator` object for you to use.

Since `Integer` class implements `Comparable`, you need not define an initial comparator. Simply call `Comparator#reverseOrder`. This call reverses the natural order of the objects.

```
List< Integer > myList = new ArrayList <> ( List.of( 7 , 1 , 42 ) ) ;
myList.sort( Comparator.reverseOrder() );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dgzkq3).

> [7, 1, 42]
>
> [42, 7, 1]

Comment: thanks. i didn't know about reversed as well

Comment: The example can be simplified to `List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(7 , 1 , 42);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because you did not return value "-1" and return "0" is not in else statement. So when you performing sort() function it return always "0" for every comparison.

Simply just rewrite an if statement and it works fine.

See example below:

```
public static class Sort implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (a < b) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a == b) {
            return 0;
        } else return -1;
    }
}
```